# Keeping the tallis katan straight underneath the shirt

Tags: tzitzis, chabad, tallit-katan

I wear my tallis katan under my shirt, and I usually tuck my shirt into my pants and pull the tzitzis up to wear they come out the top of my pants and hang down at my beltline, like [this](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/57/48/e5/5748e5322fdc608e23955467a9b9fa33--tallit-judaism.jpg).

The only problem is, this scrunches up the tallis katan and gives it some pretty bad creases after a while. I believe according to some poskim these creases change the dimensions of the beged, and potentially make them not kosher (I believe the Alter Rebbe rules this way).

What's a good way to keep the tallis katan straight under the shirt? I tried wearing a "gartel" (an elastic band around my waist over the tallis katan under my shirt) but that didn't help any.

I noticed that  a majority of Lubavitch bochurim, they do not tuck in their shirt at all. I was thinking that maybe this was because tucking in the shirt and keeping the tallis katan straight are mutually exclusive. Maybe I'm making up halacha though and there is no concern of creases and folds?

Comment: Personally, I just throw the tzitzis in the wash, check the strings when they come out, and leave it over the banister to dry. The creases fall out naturally. What sort of Tallis katan do you wear - the type with just a hole for the head, or the undershirt type?

Comment: @DonielF - I wear the "type with just a hole for the head."

Comment: @ezra Lubavitch bochurim don't but yungeleit do [tuck in their shirts]; maybe this is because the latter have wives to take care of the problem?

Comment: +1 Ezra. I have the same issue with my Tzitzis. I hope someone gives a good solution to our problem.

Comment: I don't wear the tzitzit outside, but, I hope I can offer 2 ideas - 1) If the tzitzit are long enough, wouldn't you be able to pull down enough of them to get them outside the shirt and above the beltline. I find the usually, the beltline is what causes creasing Or 2) Can you keep most of the shirt tucked in except for the corners in the area where the tzizit would have to come out?

Comment: Frankly, I don't have a problem with my (wool) beged getting scrunched up when I tuck in my shirt. I don't feel that it's appropriate to wear an untucked shirt in public, since it makes one look more slovenly.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - Do you think maybe I should go down a size? I currently wear an Israeli size 7 and I'm a little over six feet.

Comment: I wear an Israeli size 5, although I'm shorter than you. I think a larger beged stays put better though.